# PBR Material Showing weird Glossy spot

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, pbr

So I tried to render A Lykan with a PBR Shader, but I keep getting this result:
[image]

Now it's not finished yet, but as you can see the Red should be all around it, but (I'm guessing because of the fresnel part of the shader) the car has this chrome colour towards the back. I don't know how to fix this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the nodetree of the shader, your lighting setup and a pic of the model in edit mode showing that side of the car?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the reason, I don't know how but the normals were facing the opposite direction. So I just recalculated the normals and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been solved, but just to add, for anyone with similar issues, here are my best 2 tips: recalculate normals, and set normal map to non color data.